# How to access child textbox inside cell on RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I'm using a telerik RadGridView which is pretty much the same thing as a normal DataGrid in WPF. In my gridview.columns I have a GridViewDataColumn which then allows me to put a celltemplate then a datatemplate and then allow me to put different controls within a grid. I have a combobox and a textbox(only one shows at a time based on visibility property). The problem I'm having is the tab system is kind of weird and doesn't work right. When I tab to a cell in the column above, my combobox nor my textbox ever gets focus. In fact the cell turns completly white. So I was wondering how (in code behind) can I detect when a user tabs in this particular cell and manually set focus to these child elements inside this cell on the selected row?

```
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="MyDataColumn" Focusable="True" GotFocus="MyDataColumn_GotFocus_1"  Header="Header1" Width="250">
            <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid>
                        <Textbox x:name="MyTextbox" Visibility="{Binding IsTextbox}"/>
                        <Combobox x:name="MyCombobox" Visibility="{Binding IsCombo}"/>
                     </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

*Basically, how can I gain access to one of those child controls inside this GridViewDataColumn in code behind so that I can set focus to it? Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Use DataBinding. Manipulating UI Elements inside a DataTemplate in procedural code is the worst idea ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most straight forward answer to your question can be found by reading the answer to the [Access items inside the DataTemplate in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575300/access-items-inside-the-datatemplate-in-wpf) post.

However, it may be worth reading the correct answer in this [Access Elements inside a DataTemplate… How to for more than 1 DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027989/access-elements-inside-a-datatemplate-how-to-for-more-than-1-datatemplate) post also.